# How to configure private routes with react router 4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I have the following code for private route component.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class PrivaetRoute extends React.Component {

    render() {
        const {component: Component, ...rest} = this.props;

        return (
            <Route
                {...rest}
                render={props => this.props.loggedIn ? (
                    <Component {...props}/>
                ) : (
                    <Redirect
                        to={{
                            pathname: '/',
                            state: {from: this.props.location},
                        }}
                    />
                )}
            />
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        loggedIn: state.loggedIn
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivaetRoute);
```

and I have the following code for the app component that renders different routes

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Reboot from 'material-ui/Reboot';

/**
 * Local
 * */

import IndexPage from '../pages/Index';
import DashboardPage from '../pages/Dashboard';
import PrivateRoute from '../containers/PrivateRoutes';

export default class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <div>
                        <Reboot/>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path="/" component={IndexPage}/>
                            <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={DashboardPage}/>
                        </Switch>
                    </div>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

How I have designed login system is that my redux action alters the loggedIn state to be true when authentication is complete. I have checked using chrome developer tool that `loggedIn` state is indeed being set to `loggedIn:true`; however, when I change the url to `/dashboard` all the states refreshes (even the redux states) and I get redirected to `/`. What am I doing wrong?

** edit redux container

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {composeWithDevTools} from 'redux-devtools-extension';

import App from './components/App';
import reducers from './reducers';

const store = createStore(reducers, {}, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(reduxThunk)));

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

Comment: Check out this [example](https://github.com/strapi/strapi-examples/tree/master/login-react), it has the authentication flow already implemented with redux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't at all to do with the route settings.

I was using `combineReducers` function and I did not realize that it wraps all the states into a parent object so I had to access its key before accessing the actual object that I wanted to access.

Answer (score 0):

### You should use Redux

You can read about it [here](https://redux.js.org/).

### Why you should use Redux?

Because Redux serves as a global state container, it means no matter which page you go, the state will not be reset.

### How to use Redux with React-Router correctly?

Just remember one thing, Redux should be the parent of React-Router.
So it should look something like this

```
<Provider>
    <Router>
        <YourApp/>
    </Router>
</Provider>
```

*FYI: `Provider` is the state container of Redux.*

If you make `<Router>` as the parent of `<Provider>`, you'll be facing the same problem again.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes that's how I have it set up. It is just in another component. I have updated my question.

Comment: Oops, didn't notice that.